# HTTP Post request body is interpreted as text/plain instead of url-encoded.

Tags: http, https, angular, http-post

This is how my email function looks like:

```
sendEmail(fromName, fromEmail, message) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    var recieverMail = "abc@cdf.com";//service@csc.kth.se"
    var subject = "error report submitted by interactive screen"
    var recieverName = "CSC SERVICE";
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("api:key-MY_API_KEY"));
    headers.append("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mymailgunserver.mailgun.org/messages ";
    var body = "from="+fromName+"<"+fromEmail+">&to="+recieverName+"<"+recieverMail+">&subject="+subject+"&text="+message;

    return this.http.post(url,body,{headers:headers});
  }
```

[image]

As can be seen from the picture above there is also a text/plain header attached on my request, why is this?

My request body is interpreted as text/plain instead of url-encoded. Any suggestion how I might be able to solve this?

Comment: Because there's already a default, and you are only appending values. See <https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the docs you referred to is angular 1. Do you know how to override default headers in angular 2 ? I've tried to find it in the angular 2 documentation but without success.

Comment: Can you try create headers using `new Headers({"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})`, then `.append` Auth header and check?

Comment: But that is what I have already done , is it not?

Comment: I tried to create my header the way you just described and then appended my auth header and the result was exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if HTTP header names aren't case-sensitive. You could try the following:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Another possible problem would be that you forgot to import the `Headers` class:

```
import { Http, Headers, ... } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try.

```
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Request headers parameters must be "Content-Type".Because request headers parameters are case sensitive.